# CSS Sprite Full Page Background: background-position

Tags: css, background-image, fullscreen, css-sprites

I have an image, the top 80px of which I want to use for some other purpose, and remaining image, I want to set as a full page background image.

I tried setting:

```
background-position: 0px -80px
```

but it does not work.

How to properly use css sprite (background position) and full page background image?

Answer (score 0):

Either of these ([link](http://css.spritegen.com/) or [link](http://css-sprit.es/)) will generate a sprite for you and the corresponding css.

Once you have that completed use the css classes for their corresponding areas like:

```
.image1Background {
    background-image: url("thesprite.png"),
    left: -80px;
    top: 0px;
}

.image2Background {
    background-image: url("thesprite.png"),
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

<body class="image1Background">
    <div class="image2Background">
    </div>
</body>
```

Sprites are generally used for a lot of little icons to reduce the number of requests needed to download them to the client.

Answer (score -1):

i would use a div for the 80px image and the background img as body background.. something like:

```
body { background-image: url(background.gif) }
#imgtop { height: 100%; width: 100%; background-image: url(80px_image.gif) }
```

Comment: Hi.. My Basic objective is... to combine banner image and background image into one.  I am not sure if your solution tries to achieve that.

Comment: into one div? or should it only looks like one image?

Comment: That's the exact opposite of an image-sprite, which OP is asking about.